# mysql_connect - Access Denied to DB or DB doesn't exist?

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-connect

So I connect to my MySQL database using the following code:

```
function dbConnect($h,$u,$p,$n) {
  if (!$con = @mysql_connect($h,$u,$p)) {$err = err("There is a problem connecting to the database. ".mysql_error());}
  else if (!@mysql_select_db($n,$con)) {$err = err("The database \"{$n}\" could not be found. Check your spelling, make sure the database exists, and that your database credentials allows you access to this database.");}
  return (isset($err)) ? $err : "";
}
```

The problem is, if they put in a wrong username, mysql_connect will not see anything wrong with it and try to connect to the database, which outputs an error for the mysql_select_db().

So I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312401/php-mysql-connect-not-returning-false). Now normally removing the "any" user would be doable but I'm creating a phpMyAdmin-like tool and will be connecting to different databases with all types of configurations. How can I tell which username can actually connect? And how can I differentiate between the database name not existing and the username not having access to it?

Comment: What is this `if (!$con = @mysql_connect($h,$u,$p))`?

Comment: Try removing the @s. You might be quashing a useful error.

Comment: You're not following even the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312401/php-mysql-connect-not-returning-false) you mentioned.

Comment: And you're not returning the connection on success either, you're returning the error.

Comment: What the... there is nothing wrong with the way I'm using mysql_connect(). I don't return the connection because I call the function which makes the connection to the database. I've tried and tested this and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use mysql_errno()

see error codes [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-handling.html)